# Advanced custom fields and Slideshow gallery desn't work together?

Tags: plugins, gallery, advanced-custom-fields, slideshow

Im using WordPress 3.5.1 and the twentyten theme.

I'm using advanced custom fields and want to ad a slideshow. I'm using the plugin Slideshow Gallery ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slideshow-gallery/) because I've used it before and I like it.

But it doesn't work. I have a custom field that is a wysiwyg editor. When i push the button to insert a gallery nothing happens...

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Or have a suggestion of another slideshow? It must have thumbnails below,  and I want ti style it as I like, but with as little coding as possible...

Thanks! /Frida

Comment: The plugin has a button? What does it add? A shortcode? If so, you'll have to enable shortcodes for that plugin. But instead of just asking me here on a how-to, please go and search the site as there're plenty of answers about that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. I'm using ACF custom fields, and the plugin for the slideshow has a button that ads a shortcode, but it doesn't work.

ACF has a setting "Run filter "the_content"?" to use shortcodes within the WYSIWYG fieldis, its selected "Yes", but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Please contact their plugin support. Too localized for here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the shortcode to the ACF custom field? If so, you have to run [the content filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) on it so that it parses shortcodes.

Fortunately ACF has the option to do this with its WYSIWYG fields. Simply select "Run filter "the_content"?" in the field options.

Comment: I checked the settings for ACF and "Run filter "the_content"?" is selected "Yes", but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I can write the shortcode by hand in the field and the slideshow works, but I just want to click the button to get the shortcode (easier for my custom to use, than to write some code)

Comment: What's the difference between the handwritten shortcode and the one output by the button?

Comment: Well, when I click the button I get some options and fill them in, and then klick ok, and the shortcode should appear on the screen, but it doesn't, there is no output att all...

Comment: Oh OK, I understand now. Do you place the cursor in the WYSIWYG text area before clicking the button?

Comment: ACF was updated recently and I thought of this question. In the changelog it states:

"WYSIWYG Field: Fixed WYSIWYG the_content / shortcode issues - http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/5939/inconsistencies-between-standard-wysiwyg-and-acf-wysiwyg"

Let me know if it fixes your problem.